# Why I'm getting downvotes with no explanations?

Tags: discussion, voting

I recently asked a [**question**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/196474/77158) on **Arqade** and getting downvotes after answering my own question.

What could be the possible reason of downvotes?
Please help me understand. I won't ask this type of questions again if it's an off-topic.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Good question because that happened to me too -_-

Answer (score 10):

"Lack of research effort" would be my guess. It's right there in the tool-tip for the down-vote button.

Your question has not received a single close vote for being off-topic.

Answer (score -4):

As a general advice, I'd ask back for downvote reasons in the comments when unsure. Most people will explain when asked.